# I need to get multiple sets of student scores from a website daily that requires a login and put that data into a Google sheets spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First, thanks for any help in advance.  Solving this problem would save us a great deal of time!  :-)

At our middle school, we use a website called IXL  (www.ixl.com) to let the students practice math problems.We use the scores they get as grades and we can get reports from the website that let us see those grades.  The problem is that doing this for multiple grade levels and multiple subjects daily can get very time consuming.

I have dug through the website's code to find the exact link I need, and I can parse the returned information on my end.  The thing I cannot do in Google sheets is to import the raw file in order to work on it and pull out the data I need.

I found a few articles on here that let me figure out how to get to the website and even make it return codes that appear to suggest I am logged in, but I do not get the correct returned data.

The main reason for doing it with Google is that all the staff have Chromebooks and no access to Windows desktops (so no Excel)

I found code snippets that allowed me to login (I think) and get a return code of 302.  And I have figured out how to display the returned html in the cell.  But it is not correct. :-(

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp. 
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Get IXL data', 'loginToSite')
    .addToUi();
}
```

If I run this script I get the html for the default login page (www.ixl.com). However, if I am logged in in a separate tab and then paste the link from the code into the address bar I get the correct data.

Comment: function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Get IXL data', 'loginToSite')
      .addToUi();
}

Comment: The code you share here only adds a menu. Probably you are not using the login cookie you received along with the 302 response. You need that cookie to authenticate the second request (and thus obtain the desired page).